# How to get the author of specific block in a custom pallet using Aura and pallet_authorship?

Tags: authorship

I wonder if it's possible to get the peerid of the author node of a specific block in a custom pallet, I implemented the authorship pallet for the runtime in [this way](https://github.com/Datagen-Project/Datagen-Substrate-Grant/blob/cbaa29ca4042ad9c4afa31e98c6b9b9d01ed4a5f/fast_blockchain/runtime/src/lib.rs#L302).